# TypeScript is not combing javascript to single file with a Node.js TS app in VS 2015

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript1.7, visual-studio-2015

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong, or misunderstanding any concepts here.

As far as I was aware, and by the fixed status of this Connect bug report (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1581065/typescript-compile-output-into-single-file-not-working-on-save) you should be able to compile the TypeScript output into a single file by using the "Combine JavaScript output into file" option in the project properties of your TypeScript project.

This problem is reproducible on a brand new project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Community Edition via File -> New project -> TypeScript -> "Blank Node.js Web Application", I am running TypeScript 1.7.6 which is the latest at time of writing, and it is not doing this.  It is still outputting individual .js files side-by-side to the .ts counterparts.

I have also tried typing in an entire file path into that field, also tried an entire file path into the "Redirect JavaScript output to directory" option too to no avail.

[image]
[image]

The reason I want to be able to do this, is because I initiate my TypeScript compiler outside Visual Studio via Grunt task runner.

Answer (score 2):

> you should be able to compile the TypeScript output into a single file by using the "Combine JavaScript output into file" option in the project properties of your TypeScript project.

**Not if you are using external modules**. Which is what you should be doing in a NodeJS project.

## More

- Here is a 10 minute video on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0
- NodeJS config quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/node/nodejs.html
- Don't use `--out` https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply basarat. Given that and as I need to use VS as the IDE for this TypeScript project, for now, I created a Node.js .JS project rather than a .TS project, this appears to prevent VS from compiling my .TS files which is the workflow I ultimately desired anyway (as my ts compilation is handled by grunt). Thanks again.